# Parsing XML key- value pairs in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-parsing

In a XML file if i have two different root tags( i dont know what to call them ) like 
in this example i have `<units>` and `<extras>`

```
<units>

    <key_val
        android:name="mega"
        android:value="1000000" />
 ....
 ....


</units>
```

and

```
<extras>

    <key_val
        android:name="mega"
        android:value="1000000" />

    <key_val
        android:name="kilo"
        android:value="1000" />

    .....
    ......

</extras>
```

in one xml file.Then how do i parse these different root tags in different Hashmaps. Like all the key-value pairs under `<units></units>` tag should go into one hashmap and for `<extras></extras>` in other hashmap.

[XMLResourceParser](http://androidword.blogspot.in/2010/10/read-xml-resources-in-android-using.html) will work for one kind of tag. So how do modify it to do for two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This XML file does not consist of a Well-formed XML file. (See en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-formed_document)

One way to solve it: you can add a temporary root element to your XML file and parse it normally.

XML parsers will always read XML files line by line (DOM or SAX).

Another solution would be to separate your file into 2 XML files. Units.xml and Extras.xml!

Comment: I want to parse each root tag ( units, extras) separately.

Comment: If you want to parse XML, then this is the way to go. You need a Well-Formed XML file to be able to use any XML parsers. Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-formed_document

Comment: Suppose i add a temporary root, and at runtime i want all the elements of <units></units>, so will i have to iterate over the complete xml?

Comment: If you have many units tags then you will have to iterate the complete xml, if you have a single units tag, then you can make the parser stop when it detects an end tag for units.

Comment: Isnt that inefficient. Suppose i have a tag at 200th line and i want to start from there. Then i will need to go over the complete xml to get that tag

Comment: That's how it works, The parser reads the file line by line :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55933/discussion-between-diffy-and-raybaybay).